# Writing a vector of vector vector structure to a binary file

Tags: c++, vector, ofstream

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<sphere_data> >> Sphere_image ;
```

I want to write the data in sphere image to binary file.

Could any one tell me how can this be done.

I tried this Code:

```
ofstream fout("C:/Project/data.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
fout.write((char*)&Sphere_image[o], Sphere_image.size() *     
sizeof(sphere_data));
fout.close();
```

Comment: Seems your data structure has become spherical itself. You can try using three nested loops to get the nested vector contents and write to file.

Comment: Why the downvote for the question - he's tried to do something and has posted the problem very clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have nested `std::vector`s, you don't have contiguity in memory for the *whole* data structure.

So, you have to iterate through all the nested vectors *"dimensions"*, and assume contiguity of `sphere_data` instances only in the *innermost* vector.

So, your line:

> ```
> fout.write((char*)&Sphere_image[o], Sphere_image.size() *     
> sizeof(sphere_data));
> ```

must be expanded something like that:

```
for (const auto& vi : Sphere_image) { // For each outer vector
  for (const auto& vj : vi) {         // For each sub-vector
    // Now you do have contiguity for vj
    fout.write(
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(vj.data()), 
        vj.size() * sizeof(sphere_data));
  }
}
```

Note that this assumes that `sphere_data` is a **POD**, so e.g. if you have pointer data members inside `sphere_data`, that won't work.

In this case, you may provide a `sphere_data::save(std::ofstream& out) const` method, which you can call in the innermost loop. Instances of `sphere_data` will know how to serialize themselves to binary files. E.g.:

```
for (const auto& vi : Sphere_image) { // For each outer vector
  for (const auto& vj : vi) {         // For each sub-vector
    for (const auto& sd : vj) {       // For each sphere data
      sd.save(fout);
    }  
  }
}
```

You may also provide a symmetrical `sphere_data::load()` method as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped. Also while reading this binary file do I need to do the same way? only with ifstream?

Comment: Now here is a problem while reading the same. Could you please help

Comment: When reading data from file, you have to build and populate the vectors, so the code is different. I don't know your problem in details, but for example you may need to write on your files the number of vector items for each dimension, and read those numbers back and create vectors of proper sizes and then populate them with sphere_data read from files.

Comment: Yes  I was trying to do:                                   struct sphere_data
{
 int Camno; 
    int cam_x;
 int cam_y;
   
};                                                                          std::vector<sphere_data> s_pixel;                                                           std::vector<std::vector<sphere_data>> s_img;                                         std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<sphere_data> >> Sphere_image ; Now I have written the data from sphere_image to binary file now further I want to read the binary file so that I can access the data

Comment: You may want to mark the best reply as answer, up vote all the helpful replies, and then write another specific question for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

A multi-dimensional vector is not stored in consecutive memory locations, like a multi-dimensional array is.

Your vector contains a

```
 std::vector<std::vector<sphere_data>>
```

This is just an array of vector structures themselves. `Sphere_image.size()` gives you the number of values in the top level dimension of the multi-dimensional vector, that's all.

First of all, this will only work if `sphere_data` [is a POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c). If it is a class, this will not work. You have to iterate over each dimension separately:

```
ofstream fout("C:/Project/data.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

for (const auto &dim: Sphere_image)
   for (const auto &dim2:dim)
      fout.write(&dim2[0], dim2.size() * sizeof(sphere_data));

fout.close();
```

Comment: this code gives me error at &dim2[0]. The error is : argument of type "cons sphere_dat*" is incompatible with parameter of type const char".

Comment: @user6038334: The first argument needs to be `reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&dim2[0])`.  That `reinterpret_cast` is a huge red flag - specifically, that you are assuming sphere_data is POD.